# PHP MySql: Print Tree - Parent Child Checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

I have This `MySql` table for put multiple news categories(parent/child) :

```
ID  |   NAME    |  PARENTID  | DESC |
 1  |   LINUX   |     0      | NULL |
 2  |   DEBIAN  |     1      | NULL |
 3  |   SLAX    |     1      | NULL |
 4  | SLAXLIVE  |     3      | NULL |
 5  |  SWFLIVE  |     3      | NULL |
```

Now I need to print this to `jQuery` and `CSS3` html `CheckBOX` like this :

`NOTE: This is Simple Example for HTML treeview.`

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li>    <a href="#">Parent</a>

            <ul>
                <li>    <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li>    <<a href="#">Grand Child</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    <a href="#">Child</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>    <a href="#">Grand Child</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grand Child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, parent FROM " . NEWS_CATS . " ORDER BY name");
    $items = array();
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         { $items[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'label' => $row['name'], 'parent' => $row['parent']);
     }
```

i need to print `<ul><li></li></ul>` for each root cat and print `<ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>` for each parent category.

how do i can create/print this using `PHP/MySQL`:

Comment: *"jQuery and CSS3 html CheckBOX"* - is this [*bullshit bingo*](http://www.bullshitbingo.net/cards/bullshit/)? And which of the existing answers didn't work for you and why?

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion! Note: the code below is not safe for cyclic graphs (nodes may not be ancestors of themselves)!

```
printChildren($items,0);
function printChildren(array $items, $parentId){
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item['parent']==$parentId){
            print '<li>';
            print $item['label']; //or whatever you want about the current node
            print '<ul>';
            printChildren($items, $item['id']);
            print '</ul></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this error: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to printChildren() must be of the type array, null given, called in line ..`

Comment: You can use this code AFTER yours (because that collected the $items array). Try to understand the code instead of simple copy paste: printChildren uses your $items to draw a subtree (beginning in the node $parentId) and the call ```printChildren($items,0)``` causes the whole tree to be drawn (the subtree of the root).