# Turning a SQL query into a nested list with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-lists

I am attempting to turn the results of a SQL query into a nested <ul> list using PHP and don't know how to do so. Here's a sample table I've made up to illustrate:

```
|id(PK)|priority|feature                                |parent_id(FK?)|
|-----:|-------:|---------------------------------------|-------------:|
|    1 |    200 | Made from renewable resources         | NULL         |
|    2 |   1000 | 5 imprint methods available:          | NULL         |
|    3 |    100 | Deboss/Emboss                         | 2            |
|    4 |    400 | Recyclable                            | NULL         |
|    5 |    400 | Screen Printed: unlimited spot colors | 2            |
|    6 |    300 | Traditional 4-Color Process           | 2            |
|    7 |    100 | Made & printed in the U.S.A.          | NULL         |
|    8 |    300 | Biodegradable                         | NULL         |
|    9 |    200 | Hot Stamp                             | 2            |
```

The `priority` field is just a `SMALLINT` and would be used to sort the list in descending order. The `parent_id` field references the `id` field in this same table, to indicate if that row should be in a nested <ul>. With this table, I'd like the output from PHP to be:

- 5 imprint methods available:

  - Screen Printed: unlimited spot colors
  - Traditional 4-Color Process
  - Hot Stamp
  - Deboss/Emboss
- Recyclable
- Biodegradable
- Made from renewable resources
- Made & printed in the U.S.A.

I'm completely open to altering the table as needed to make this possible, if its current arrangement isn't conducive to the end result I'm looking to achieve. Ideas/thoughts?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM my_table x LEFT JOIN my_table y ON y.parent = x.id WHERE x.parent IS NULL ORDER BY...` or just `SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY COALESCE(parent,id), priority DESC, id` or something like that. As for alternative models, you might look at Mike Hillyer's excellent article.

Comment: @Strum : i think you are looking for this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480266/php-mysql-print-tree-parent-child-checkbox

Comment: That was the solution, @prakashtank! I'm not too thrilled by all of the extra empty &lt;ul&gt;&lt;/ul&gt; tags that are in the list, but as long as they don't cause any harm, then I can live with them. Thank you so much! :~)