# php array iteration visually parent > child

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

managed to create array tree with childs. Looks like this.

[image]

Want to try printing it out with same levels.

```
<ul>
<li>cat1</li>
<ul><li>sub-cat</li>
  <ul><li>subsub-cat</li>
    <ul><li>subsubsub-cat</li>
      <ul><li>subsubsubsub-cat</li></ul>
    <li>subcub-cat2</li>
<ul></ul></ul></ul></ul>
<li>cat2</li>
</ul>
```

Need to use iterative angle. At least point me to to the right direction.

It doesn't have to be with UL LI, can be with -- -- or some sort similar, just need to print it out using iterative methods.

Comment: You can call a function recursively to show parent and then children under that parent.

Comment: I know, but my task is to do it iteratively, Ive done it recursively.

Comment: This answer will be helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23480561/5503275

Comment: use a while that checks if child exist  in  a foreach block

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
<ul>
    <?php parse($array); ?>
</ul>
<?php
function parse($array) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        ?>
        <li><?php echo $value->name; ?>

            <?php if (!empty($value->child)) { ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php parse($value->child); ?>
                </ul>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

I've already faced this problem and used the same trick to handle.

Comment: Is this iterative use of the loop though? Since it does call itself

Comment: You need to use recursive function here. By using only iteration, we must have depth of array, and then write a separate loop for each level. Which will not be efficient.

Comment: I figured kinda, but I created something like this, how ever, it doesnt not print sbusub-cat2 since it is in a child of a child. http://collabedit.com/vc2mn

Comment: It will parse only one branch to deepest level and leave others. By the way, what is the problem with recursion?

Comment: There is not problem in specific, Ive just been given a task where I have to write a code with iteration method. So Im trying to get as closest as possible to it. Ive allready done the recursive style.

Comment: Okay fine. Then it's a challenge. Go Ahead!

Comment: any ideas how should I proceed then maybe? :D

Answer (score 0):

It is not the exact solution but you can use something like this

```
foreach( $array as $item ){
    echo $item['id'].'<br>';
    while(isset($item['child'])){
        $item = $item['child'];
        echo $item['id'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

here is the code sample that i generated
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/068f8b2d79cb5e210a6ee4c8e14c1a8649ab0dea

Comment: Thanks for the code! But it does only print trough the deepest level of childs.
so it skips if there is 2 childs tree