# Html TreeView in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, treeview

I'm generating tree view on the basic of data stored in a table. For static fixed data it is working fine but i don't know how to display a growing tree in database. here is my table[image]

Every user that is loged into website is parent in the table. for example, if A is loged in then its static html code will look like this

```
<ul>
    <li>A
        <ul>
            <li>B
                <ul>
                    <li>C
                        <ul>
                            <li>Y</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>J</li>
    <li>K</li>
</ul>
```

But that tree can grow further. For example 'J' and 'K' may have more children after their child signup to website. I want to make it dynamic using php as users continue to signup into website.Please help

Comment: Based on my understanding, this is a bit odd, because what if you have a lot of users? 1M for example. How can you handle that? And that is not a good practice.

Comment: What version of MySQL? They introduced recursive queries in MySQL 8.0: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: You should go through all user record recursively.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh yes, but the problem is how should use html tags in recursion. I unable to design the logic for proper opening and closing tags in recursion.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680550/php-array-iteration-visually-parent-child/50680769#50680769